# getting z_filters via REST

Tags: product, orders, customer, rest-api

We are trying to grab all data from a **magento 1.x-Shop** to process them for some statistics.

I was able to connect to the shop and grab **product**, **customers**, **orders** and **stockitems** so far

I saw at the product-data:

z_filter_winegrower: '245',

z_filter_vintage: '19',

z_filter_country: '43',

z_filter_region: '23',

.... we need this data in human language, not in **IDs** 
=> how to?

I tried

http://magentohost/api/rest/filters

http://magentohost/api/rest/z_filters

http://magentohost/api/rest/filter_groups

so far and nothing worked

Thank you very much!